# Troubleshooting EKS IO for containerized application

Tags: kubernetes, jvm, amazon-eks, amazon-efs

I'm trying to figure out some performance issues that I'm seeing with an application we've moved to EKS. We containerized a Java app a while ago. What we just noticed is that running in EKS it appears to be suffering from some kind of IO issues. Our EKS env uses EFS for storage. When the problem is occurring, if I run iotop on one of my nodes I can see one of the application threads sitting around 99%, ie spending 99% of its time waiting on IO. The application runs an in memory database but the operations causing trouble are writes to disk when a storm of record changes are required. I think they are very small writes. I don't think we ever saw these issues when the application was running on physical servers except when we had dying hardware.

Just wondering how to troubleshoot this and if there are any things to try? I'm not even suggesting that there is some kind of issue with what EKS is doing but clearly the IO is not behaving the way the application expects.

Thanks!

So far I've managed to track down the issue via iotop and have been looking at EFS docs.

Comment: Are you using requests/limits? If so, what are they set to?

Answer (score 0):

I'll followup my own question. The application we containerized does not do batching of writes, so it is performing thousands of small writes occasionally. We did some performance testing of EFS, EFS one zone and EBS and in this scenario EBS is probably 5-10x faster than EFS. I think it's simply a latency thing.